# CSS : How do I line up the elements in my header using css?

Tags: html, css, header, center

I want all the elements in my header to be in a horizontal line in line with each other. I also want them to be centered on the Grey header block. Here is what it looks like so far.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSCpq.png) This is my first website so I'm just playing around at the moment so I would appreciate any help or advice.

```css
* 
  ====================================
  HEADER
  ====================================
*/

header {
 background-color: grey;
 opacity: 50%;
 width: 100%;
}

#logo {
 float: left;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

#logo img {
 width: 15%;
 height: 15%;
}

#navigation { 
 margin: auto;
 clear: both;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
 color: #fff;
}

#navigation li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 padding-bottom: 0.75px;
}

.social-media {
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0 1.5em 0 0;
}

.social-media ul li {
 display: inline;
}

.social-media img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>

      <nav id="main-controls">
        <ul id="navigation">
          <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="social-media">
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
          <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
          <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
          <a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img src="img/google+.png" alt="Google Plus"></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="Linked In"></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

An updated version of your CSS:

```
* 
  ====================================
  HEADER
  ====================================
*/

header {
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#logo img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
}

#navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#navigation li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 0.75px;
}

.social-media {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1.5em 0 0;
}

.social-media ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-media img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
```

This should take care of aligning all elements horizontally. I removed a float property declared, and used `display: inline-block` instead on all stacked elements.